# Plotting rectangle side by side from Coordinates

Tags: gnuplot

I have a text file named "Rect.txt" containing the Coordinates (x0,y0,x1,y1) of four sides of 31 rectangles. Like this-

```
#x0  y0   x1       y1
0  0  0.542061  0.0818535  
0.84759  0  0.862024  0.184529  
0.84759  0.788795  1  1  
0  0.788795  0.293575  0.954972  
0.293575  0.788795  0.84759  0.954972  
0.293575  0.954972  0.84759  1  
0  0.954972  0.293575  1  
0.56353  0  0.84759  0.110016  
0.56353  0.110016  0.704626  0.221483  
0  0.110016  0.284186  0.24485  
0.542061  0  0.56353  0.0818535  
0.542061  0.0818535  0.56353  0.110016  
0  0.0818535  0.206262  0.106572  
0.206262  0.0818535  0.542061  0.106572  
0.206262  0.106572  0.542061  0.110016  
0  0.106572  0.206262  0.110016  
0.704626  0.110016  0.84759  0.221483  
0.704626  0.221483  0.755493  0.728256  
0.56353  0.221483  0.704626  0.788795  
0.284186  0.110016  0.56353  0.24485  
0.284186  0.24485  0.56353  0.788795  
0  0.24485  0.00535607  0.622112  
0.755493  0.221483  0.84759  0.728256  
0.755493  0.728256  0.84759  0.788795  
0.704626  0.728256  0.755493  0.788795  
0.862024  0  1  0.184529  
0.862024  0.184529  1  0.788795  
0.84759  0.184529  0.862024  0.788795  
0.00535607  0.24485  0.284186  0.622112  
0.00535607  0.622112  0.284186  0.788795  
0  0.622112  0.00535607  0.788795  .......etc
```

I want to plot the rectangles using these coordinates. Which supposed to look something like this-

[image]

In gnuplot I used the command-

```
plot "Rect.txt" w l
```

But I am getting the following image-

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you must use a plotting style which supports plotting of variable sized rectangles. In your case, the best option is the `boxxyerrorbars` style, which expects four values: the center's x and y value, and the half width, and half height:

```
plot 'Rect.txt' using (($1+$3)/2):(($2+$4)/2):(($3-$1)/2):(($4-$2)/2) \
    w boxxyerrorbars lw 2 notitle
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know about 'boxxyerrorbars' option. Voted up.